# How to delete all rows of group in Pandas if the group meets condition?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

I have a dataframe that looks somewhat like this (this only shows one num, id combination):

```
num    id   cat   month   year    quantity
1      2    A       8     2019      0.0
1      2    A       2     2021      2.0
1      2    B       2     2018      2.0
1      2    B       4     2018      2.0
1      2    B       9     2020      2.0
1      2    B       10    2020      -2.0
1      2    C       3     2021      -1.0
1      2    D       3     2018      2.0
```

I am working on a case where I need to compute sums of quantity for each <num, id, cat, year> combination. It does not make sense for sums to be negative. I discovered that sometimes, quantities did not get cancelled out because for a certain num, a negative value was entered for the wrong category. To fix this, I wrote logic where sum of negatives = sum of positives for a certain <num, id, year> group would mean all rows of this group must be removed from original dataframe. Original dataframe consists of many such nums, and ids.
I am struggling to write this logic.
Here is my skeleton

```
def remove_cancelled_rows(df):
    #if sum of positive quantities in group == sum of negative quantities:
        #remove all rows from group
new_df = new_df.groupby('year').apply(lambda x:remove_cancelled_rows()).reset_index()
```

Comment: What are you expected results form the dataset given?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, removes records with groups that sum less than zero:

```
df[df.groupby(['num','id','cat','year'])['quantity'].transform('sum') > 0]
```

Output:

```
   num  id cat  month  year  quantity
1    1   2   A      2  2021       2.0
2    1   2   B      2  2018       2.0
3    1   2   B      4  2018       2.0
7    1   2   D      3  2018       2.0
```